# Baker's Yeast and distillation?

Tags: distillation

I have made a wine a few days ago. I used apples and grapes but that is not what is important. For my yeast I used baker's yeast. YES!!! I do know that I should have used wine yeast to get better flavor and alcohol yield. Anyway, what I  would like to know is what flavors I would get if I distill my wine mixture.

Comment: How far you want to go with distillation? If you go up to 98% and water it down back to 40% you'll have next to none taste. If you'll just pump it from 10% to 20%, it'll taste mostly like the original wine. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

When properly distilled the spirit product is flavorless.

Edit: However it's hard to achieve such quality. You can simulate your distilled spirit by adding a small portion to un flavored 100 proof vodka (is 50% Alcohol, mostly 50% water). Once you get a flavor you like you can then use those ratios as a distillation target.

Comment: As far as I know, traditional whisky distillers would not agree. Or cognac distillers. And cognac is distilled wine, a bit like what op is trying to do.

Comment: @Mołot that's why you see those spirits undergo double or triple distillation because they intentionally gasify more than just alcohol. But it is possible to only extract alcohol and obtain a 200 proof spirit in one distillation which is colorless and flavorless.

Answer (score 0):

If you did distill it, I would guess that you would not get nearly enough alcohol, as bakers yeast ferments to hot and fast to produce an alcoholic beverage to drink. Also as someone who tried this with a gallon of beer, you get a very bready/malty taste witch would go strangley with fruit, as in a brandy, also if you were to age this in a oak cask like done with most dark alcohol, you could probably get out the off flavor.